# Adding Click Event Listeners During Iteration?

Tags: javascript, html, loops, events, electron

I'm trying to add a click event listener to a bunch of newly created divs in a for loop. The issue I'm having is that only the last div keeps its event listener. I've read up about closures and read several other posts and questions and their answers, and as far as I can tell I have it set up correctly. But it still isn't working for me. Only the final div to be iterated is receiving the event listener.

```js
function edit_entry(k) {
    wrd_input.value = k;
    def_input.value = lexicon[k][1];
    wrd_input.onkeyup();

    delete lexicon[k];
    rewrite_entries();
}

function rewrite_entries(keys = null) {
    if (keys === null) { keys = []; }
    let sorted_keys = sort_lex_keys();
    lex_body.style.color = 'rgb(200, 200, 200)';
    lex_body.innerHTML = '';

    sorted_keys.forEach((key) => {
        if (!keys.length || keys.includes(key)) {
        lex_body.innerHTML += 
        `<div class='lex-entry' id=${key}><i>${key}</i>\n<p class='pronunciation'>${lexicon[key][0]}</p>${lexicon[key][1]}</div>\n`;
        let entry = document.getElementById(key)
        entry.addEventListener('click', edit_entry.bind(this, key) );
        }
    });
}
```

Current state of the relevant code above. If somebody knows the issue, it'd be very helpful.
If it's relevant, this code is running via Electron (17.0.0).

An attempted solution, using an anonymous arrow function instead of a bind:

```js
entry.addEventListener('click', () => edit_entry(key) );
```

yields the same result.

---

Update:
Changing the .innerHTML attribute of something apparently strips all event listeners. So the solution was simply to create the element completely in js, add it to the container, and *then* add the listener. This change to the `forEach` loop solves the problem:

```js
    sorted_keys.forEach((key) => {
        if (!keys.length || keys.includes(key)) {
            let entry = document.createElement('div');
            entry.className = 'lex-entry';
            
            let word = document.createElement('p');
            word.appendChild( document.createTextNode(key) );
            word.style.fontStyle = 'italic';
            
            let pron = document.createElement('p');
            pron.className = 'pronunciation';
            pron.appendChild( document.createTextNode(lexicon[key][0]) );
            
            let defn = document.createTextNode(lexicon[key][1]);
            
            entry.append(word, pron, defn);
            entry.addEventListener('click', () => edit_entry(key) );

            lex_body.appendChild(entry);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So a few things crosses my mind:

Firstly, `edit_entry.bind(this, key);`: Are you certain `this` is pointing to what you want? It should be pointing to the `window` object. Also, is there any reason to bind context for that particular function?

Secondly `innerHTML`: Generally it's discouraged to use `innerHTML` directly. I don't know how/when the browser layouts changes to `innerHTML`, the `div` might not be on the page when you call `getElementById`. As an alternative, you could try `document.createElement("div")`, set its properties accordingly and finally append it to `lex_body`.

*Edit*

From [mdn](http://Please%20note%20that%20using%20innerHTML%20to%20append%20html%20elements%20(e.g.%20el.innerHTML%20+=%20%22%3Ca%20href=%27...%27%3Elink%3C/a%3E%22)%20will%20result%20in%20the%20removal%20of%20any%20previously%20set%20event%20listeners.%20That%20is,%20after%20you%20append%20any%20HTML%20element%20that%20way%20you%20won%27t%20be%20able%20to%20listen%20to%20the%20previously%20set%20event%20listeners.):

> Please note that using innerHTML to append html elements (e.g. el.innerHTML += "link") will result in the removal of any previously set event listeners. That is, after you append any HTML element that way you won't be able to listen to the previously set event listeners.

Comment: Yep I've made the same experience. Using the old shool method `document.createElement()` does the trick. Whatever the differences to innerHTML are.

Comment: Oh wow, I did not know that about the `innerHTML` thing. Your solution did the trick - just creating the element from scratch in js, adding the listener, and then adding it to the container does the trick. 
I'm new-ish to JS coming from a Pythonic background, and these are _not_ the kinds of problems I'm used to solving. Thanks!
I'll update the post soon with my full solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think that binding the function every time with `this` is overriding the binding every time, that should be the reason that you are only getting the last one's event.

Inside of the `forEach` lambda, the `this` keyword refers to the internal class that is calling the `forEach` not your `rewrite_entries` function. Try not binding the call, like so:

```js
entry.addEventListener('click', () => edit_entry(key) );
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work either. It adds the event listener to the final div, none of the others.